# Cannot move vertical lines upwards (memory mapped graphics)

Tags: assembly, tasm

I am trying to move a vertical line upwards through video mode 13. But everytime I do so, it moves downward. This is also my first time in memory mapped graphics. Can somebody help me? I am using Tasm/windows

Here is my macro:

```
drawSquare MACRO color,cy,cx,dy,dx
    mov ah,06
    mov al, 0
    mov bh,color
    mov ch,cy
    mov cl,cx
    mov dh,dy
    mov dl,dx
    int 10h
endm

clearscreen MACRO
    drawSquare 00h, 00h, 00h, 18h, 27h
 endm
```

---

```
include macros.txt
.model small
.stack
.data

saveMode db ?
xVal dw 40
yVal dw 90

R db 0
G db 0
B db 63


lengths dw 0

.code
    main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    call SetVideoMode
    call SetScreenBackground       ;blue for the tank


    mov lengths, 20
    call line_vertical
    move:
        mov ah, 07
        int 21h

        cmp al, "w"
        je up
        jmp outA

        up:
        dec yVal
        clearscreen

        mov lengths, 20
        call line_vertical

    jmp move
    outA:

    call RestoreVideoMode

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
main endp
SetScreenBackground proc
    mov dx, 3c8h
    mov al, 0
    out dx, al

    mov dx, 3c9h
    mov al, R
    out dx, al

    mov al, G
    out dx, al

    mov al, B
    out dx, al
    ret
SetScreenBackground endp 

SetVideoMode proc
    mov ah, 0fh
    int 10h
    mov saveMode, al

    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 13h
    int 10h

    push 0A000h
    pop es
    ret
SetVideoMode endp

RestoreVideoMode proc
    mov ah, 10h
    int 16h

    mov ah, 0
    mov al, saveMode
    int 10h
    ret
RestoreVideoMode endp

line_horizontal proc
    mov dx, 3c8h
    mov al, 1
    out dx, al

    mov dx, 3c9h
    mov al, 255
    out dx, al
    mov al, 255
    out dx, al
    mov al, 255
    out dx, al

    mov ax, 320
    mul yVal
    add ax, xVal

    mov cx, lengths
    mov di, ax

    L1:
        mov BYTE PTR es:[di], 1
        add di, 1
    loop L1

    ret
line_horizontal endp

line_vertical proc
    mov dx, 3c8h
    mov al, 1
    out dx, al

    mov dx, 3c9h
    mov al, 255
    out dx, al
    mov al, 255
    out dx, al
    mov al, 255
    out dx, al

    mov cx, lengths

    L2:
        mov ax, 320
        mul yVal
        add ax, xVal

        mov di, ax

        mov BYTE PTR es:[di], 1

        inc yVal
    loop L2
    ret
line_vertical endp
end main
```

Comment: `line_vertical` modified `yVal` in the `L2` loop. You should probably change that so that you operate on a copy of `yVal` held in a register or on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found the answer. The problem is that i only decremented it by one. My line_vertical procedure draws line from top to bottom. Therefore, the latest value for yVal is the bottom part of the line. For the line to move upwards, I need to reset it back to the top plus the number of pixels I want it to move. To do so;

yVal -= (length of line + pixels to move);

i just need to change my

```
dec yVal
```

into

```
sub yVal, 25
```

and it worked perfectly. :D